# How can I move and resize features with an ArcView license?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, editing, feature-class, representation

this might be a silly question but I have a problem with moving features in ArcGis 10. I'm only using the ArcView license so the editing tool "representation" is deactivated.

Is there an easy way to simply move my selected features (maybe by converting them?)?

Also I need to "Resize" my selected features by a certain percentage!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? What do you mean by 'move' - change feature coordinates manually using your mouse pointer?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant!

Comment: Do this: right-click your layer -> Edit Features -> Start editing (if you can click continue on all messages appearing you are good). Then you select the feature(s) that you want to move, and move them with the arrow from the *Editor toolbar* (regular arrow won't do it!).

Comment: Are you trying to edit representations? If so do you have Standard or Advanced license of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: Thanks Martin! That was easier than I thought. Do you know a way how I can "Resize" my selected features by a certain percentage or simply make them bigger?

Comment: @Martin looks like you should convert your Comment to an Answer so the asker can Accept it and then research/ask the new Question about resizing features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When moving your features manually, right-click your layer -> Edit Features -> Start editing (if you can click continue on all messages appearing you are good).

Then you select the feature(s) that you want to move, and move them with the arrow from the Editor toolbar (regular arrow won't do it!).

You can resize polygons with the Buffer function on the Editor menu in the toolbar. Use negative buffer distance to shrink and vice versa. This does only apply to selected features, which also the [Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000) function does when outside of an edit session. However, the buffer value is a specific distance rather than a percentage.